# Removing given name in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, biber

I wish to use all the `DeclareNameFormat` code of the standard biblatex styles, but I do not want to write given names nor initials in the bibliography. Is it possible to empty the constant `\namepartgiven` `\AtEveryBibitem`? I guess this should do the trick, right? How to clear (for example) parts of the name list? I know how to clear fields, but not parts of the author name.

This is a bad solution, for example:

`\DeclareNameFormat{author}{\namepartfamily}`

because I lose the 'et al.' and all the smartness of the default citing styles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`biblatex` already has a name format called `labelname` which does this. It also allows for disambiguation on the basis of the `uniquename` option if you use that. Just add this to your preamble:

```
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{labelname}
```

If you don't wan't the initials in the following MWE, then leave out the `uniquename=init` option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{a,
  author = {Doe, Jane and Doe, John},
  title = {A Title},
  date = {2021}
}
@book{b,
  author = {Doe, Barry and Doe, Sheila},
  title = {Another Title},
  date = {2021}
}
@book{c,
  author = {Author, An and Writer, Another},
  title = {Yet Another Title},
  date = {2021}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[uniquename=init]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{labelname}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

### Addendum: Why does this work?

`biblatex` creates a special field for citations called `labelname`. Most often this is just the family name, but can include a given name or initial if we need to remove ambiguity. In order to print this field, we need a name format that just prints the family name. This name format is defined in `biblatex.def` as:

```
\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
    \usebibmacro{name:family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \or
    \ifuseprefix
      {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiveni}
        {\namepartprefix}
        {\namepartsuffixi}}
      {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiveni}
        {\namepartprefixi}
        {\namepartsuffixi}}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:given-family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \fi
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
```

In this format there is logic for disambiguation. But if disambiguation isn't needed, then the macro `name:family` (also defined in `biblatex.def`) is called to print just the family name.

Now all we need to do is tell `biblatex` to use this format when printing names in the bibliography. The simplest and most global way to do this is to change the default way names are printed from `given-family` to `labelname`. We do this using an alias:

```
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{labelname}
```

Be aware that not all bibliography styles use the `default` name format in the bibliography though. Some use `sortname` so you'd need to change that instead.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Can I ask you to explain why this works? The biblatex documentation just goes way above my head.

Comment: The `biblatex` documentation can be confusing. But if you read enough of it, things do begin to make sense. I also highly recommend looking at the `biblatex` source files. They are actually quite readable and you can learn a lot about how things work and how to modify things just by seeing how things are set up by default. The key files are `biblatex.def`, `standard.bbx` and possibly other `cbx` and `bbx` files if you're using an author date or author title style.

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed explanation!